# Excel VLOOKUP Exam Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I have a problem on excel and it says I have to few arguments.

The questions is that I have to create ONE formula to calculate the grade average of 3 exams.

I have already tried creating a table of all the grades from A+ to E- and valued them to 15 to 1. and just did vlookup on each grade individually and then divided by 3. From here the problems started, I added a vlookup again (to find the total grade not just the value of the number) and it comes up with few arguments so please help thanks. Below is a screen shot of what I have so far.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:D2=G$2:G$16)*(H$2:H$16))/COUNTA(B2:D2)
```

The reverse lookup would be MATCH with -1 not VLOOKUP with FALSE.

```
=INDEX(G$2:G$16, MATCH(SUMPRODUCT((B2:D2=G$2:G$16)*(H$2:H$16))/COUNTA(B2:D2), H$2:H$16, -1))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks but, it need to be rounded and to the grade (A, A-, B+) , also idk it is NEEDS to be rounded but i think it does to correlate to the table

Comment: OMG nvm thanks so much i just needed to add a few little things, thanks so much tho

Comment: You might want to use ROUND, ROUNDUP or ROUNDDOWN with the reverse lookup.

Comment: well when i do, A+,A+, E- is come out as E- when in reality it should come out as B-

Comment: If you are rounding to an integer, use 0 instead of -1 for the match type.

Comment: if i replaced the -1 with a 0 it will just replace the box with a N/A

Comment: then you've misplaced or otherwise misused the round.

Comment: humm, @Jeeped sorry to bother you but i have used that formula =INDEX(L$2:L$16,MATCH(SUMPRODUCT((E2:G2=L$2:L$16)*(M$2:M$16))/COUNTA(E2:G2), M$2:M$16,-1)) and i have ran into a problem and i figure it out, somehow is there is A, A+ and B+ it comes out as a C+, idk why but i have more info in my latest question about the problem if that could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your proposed VLOOKUP will work, but it looks to me as if you have one too few open parenthesis. The color codes of the parenthesis show which "open (" belongs to which "close ) ".

It looks to me like you have =VLOOKUP ( ( lookup1 + lookup2 + lookup3) / 3) ...and then the rest isn't part of the vlookup anymore.   You probably just need one more open paren.

=VLOOKUP ( ( ( lookup1 + lookup2 + lookup3) / 3) , range,2,false)

[Maybe this image will help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIEPo.png)

Comment: The division by 3 will end up in a decimal 2 out of 3 times. If it does, VLOOKUP's FALSE will always return an error looking through a column of integers and if TRUE, the sort order of the integers is backwards. You would need MATCH with -1 as the match type for integers in descending order.

Comment: That makes sense .. thanks for the comment @Jeeped.   I probably should have worked on the solution a bit more.  I was merely addressing the unbalanced parenthesis as the reason for the "too few arguments" error.

Comment: If you want to edit in an INDEX/MATCH, I'd be happy to upvote but I can't with the currently incomplete solution.